# SQL query to Find number of customers in the list

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Code used

```
Select c.CustomerID
From SalesLT.Customer c
UNION ALL
Select sod.UnitPrice
From SalesLT.SalesOrderDetail sod
where
```

I am trying to solve this question shown below. I believe we are supposed to use UNION?

```
Find number of customers in the list found above.
```

SOLVED

Comment: what is your RDBMS and its version ?

Comment: SQL server. Adventurework 2012

Comment: you'd be looking for a JOIN for this, not a UNION. unfortunately SO doesn't accept questions that clearly related to student assignments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join both the tables via a left join so that all customers are considered:

```
SELECT c.customerId, SUM(COALESCE(soh.subTotal,0)) order_amount
FROM Customer as c 
LEFT JOIN SalesOrderHeader AS soh ON soh.customerId = c.customerId 
GROUP BY c.customerId
HAVING SUM(COALESCE(soh.subTotal,0)) < 14896.45
```

Do not limit the output to only those who have ordered by using coalesce to provide zero if there is no order value present.

Answer (score 0):

You can go for GROUP BY customerId and see if sum of subtotal is lesser than recommended amount.

```sql
SELECT c.customerId
FROM Customer as c 
left outer join SalesOrderHeader as soh
on soh.customerId = c.customerId 
GROUP BY c.customerID
HAVING SUM(soh.subotal) < 14896.45
```

Comment: Thank you, seems to work but how will we do "Customers who have not placed an order are considered to have ordered $0.00."?

Comment: As we are applying left outer join, all customers are considered irrespective of they placed orders or not.